# Textview extends past tablelayout on fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set up a tablelayout with a width of 50dp. I added a tableRow and used fill parent then added a textview fill parrent. With both the tablerow and textview set to fill parrent should the textview have a width of 50dp ?  The table layout holds a seekbar and a textview that I need to be centered.

```
          <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/TB1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <!-- Red -->

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowR1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewR"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="255"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF00"
            android:textSize="43dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowR2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarr"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mastersliderback"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:thumb="@drawable/imgsliderred70" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Post a picture if my answer doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table will always be as wide as your widest row. Your second `TableRow` is `wrap_content` with a `SeekBar` that is `300dp`. Therefore your table will be `300dp` which overrides the `50dp` `width` you set in `TableLayout`.

I think a `LinearLayout` would be better suited for what you are doing though.

Comment: Thank you Linear does work better. I missed the 300dp on the seekbar which was the issue.